# nvd3 lineWithFocusChart Invalid value error when resizing

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

LineChart with time scale d3.time.format will resize fluidly with window.
lineWithFocusChart never has errors on draw, but while resizing it throws many:

`d3.js:8756 Error: Invalid value for <rect> attribute width="NaN"`

Sometimes the error stops on mouseup, but many times it keeps throwing after resize is done, which amounts to a memory leak.

*I am looking for a working example of this chart type showing date/time in responsive layout, or recommended method for handling time data with focus brush resizing.*

Things I have tried:

- using parseDate() on my data - no change
- use different timescale - no change
- set chart transition to 0 - no change

the dates are Javascript date objects - ie new Date()
resizing using nvd3:

```
                nv.utils.windowResize(function () {
                    chart.update();
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

workaround with newest nvd3:

```
chart.focusEnable( false );
chart.update();
chart.focusEnable( thisWidget.showZoomStrip );
```

Where thisWidget.showZoomStrip is my local setting for displaying the brush so this works for regular line chart. This is possible because newest (1.8.2) combined the LineChart and LineWithFocusChart, so I can turn off the brush while resizing.

Comment: This workaround isn't so great either - redrawing chart after resizing still has the errors. Clicking the legend stops them. Going to look at what is triggered by legend that is different

Comment: Further research - nvd3 brush is an implementation of d3 brush, I might be able to use some methods on it directly to avoid the errors when using time scale.

Comment: Removed all scale and tick formatting from .x2Axis - ie use defaults of d3 brush provided by nvd3: no change